# PURL url parser not

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to use `allmarkedup / purl` to get access to the URL parameters.

But, I'm doing something wrong.

I added `purl.js` to my Rails app.

I put this into `application.js`:

```
var url = $.url();
alert(url);
```

And I get a popup with:

```
[object Object]
```

Comment: Use `console.log(url)` or `alert(JSON.stringify(url))`

Comment: Thanks - I used the json one and it worked!  If you create an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `alert` to debug your code as anything you pass to it will be `toString`ed:

```
{}.toString() == [object Object]
[].toString() == [object Array]
...
```

Use the console instead:

```
console.log(url); // accepts any type, any expression
```

The other way around the problem is to alert your object as JSON, effectively turning it into a string:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(url));
```

But I'd say just forget about `alert`.